# filter for thumbnail not working for custom taxonomy term

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I am using a hook to change the appearance of categories on my website.

my problem is, it works fine for product categories but when i decided to use a custom taxonomy for the purpose, they are appearing but without their image ( i set an image field up with ACF for the custom tax ; return format image array ) it is the custom tax term image that is missing whereas everything else works ( the custom tax link, and name are showing )

I have no idea where I am going wrong with it, i have tried endless amounts of different things, it cannot find the thumbnail ID of the custom taxonomy.

Can anybody give me some advice please.

```
if ( ! function_exists('custom_subcategory_thumbnail') ):

        remove_action('woocommerce_before_subcategory_title', 'woocommerce_subcategory_thumbnail');

        add_action('woocommerce_before_subcategory_title', 'custom_subcategory_thumbnail', 10, 1);

        function custom_subcategory_thumbnail( $category ) {

    

            $thumbnail_id           = get_term_meta( $category->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
            
        /*    echo '<pre>';
            var_dump($testing);
            echo '</pre>';*/
        //    var_dump($thumbnail_id);

            
          //  $taxonomy = $queried_object->taxonomy;
           // $wpimage = get_field('workplace_thumb', 'workplaces' . '_' . $category->term_id);
          /*  echo '<pre>';
            print_r($thumbnail_id);echo '</pre>';*/
           
         //   $attachment_id = get_field( 'workplace_thumb', 'workplaces_' . $category->term_id );
    
/*
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($attachment_id);
            echo '</pre>';*/
            if ( $thumbnail_id ) {

                $image        = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, 'woocommerce_single' );

                $image        = $image[0];

                $image_srcset = function_exists( 'wp_get_attachment_image_srcset' ) ? wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $thumbnail_id, 'shop_single_image_size' ) : false;

                $image_sizes  = function_exists( 'wp_get_attachment_image_sizes' ) ? wp_get_attachment_image_sizes( $thumbnail_id, 'shop_single_image_size' ) : false;

            }
            
            
            else{

                $image        = wc_placeholder_img_src();

                $image_srcset = $image_sizes = false;

            }

    

            if ( $image ) {

                // Prevent esc_url from breaking spaces in urls for image embeds

                // Ref: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23605

                $image = str_replace( ' ', '%20', $image );

    

                echo '<div class="banner-box__image brand-grayscale">
                <a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $category, 'product_cat' ) ) . '" >
                <span class=" woocommerce-loop-category__thumbnail brand-grayscale" style="background-image :url(' . esc_url( $image ) . ');"></span></a>

            </div>';

            }

        }

        endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out,
in case anyone else needs it,

it was really simple, and just used an elseif for when the id was not found & changed the custom field name to the custom taxonomy image field ( workplace_thumb ) for that taxonomy id.

```
  if ( ! function_exists('custom_subcategory_thumbnail') ):

        remove_action('woocommerce_before_subcategory_title', 'woocommerce_subcategory_thumbnail');

        add_action('woocommerce_before_subcategory_title', 'custom_subcategory_thumbnail', 10, 1);

        function custom_subcategory_thumbnail( $category ) {

    

            $thumbnail_id           = get_term_meta( $category->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
           /* $term = get_field('workplace_thumb', 'workplace_' . $category->post_ID);


            echo '<pre>';
            echo "thumbnail id variable value vardump: ";echo '<br />';
            var_dump($thumbnail_id); echo '<br />';
            echo 'term variable value: ';echo '<br />';
           var_dump($term);echo '<br />';
           echo "Category value:";echo '<br />';
           var_dump($category);echo '<br />';
           echo '</pre>';*/
            
          //  $taxonomy = $queried_object->taxonomy;
           // $wpimage = get_field('workplace_thumb', 'workplaces' . '_' . $category->term_id);
          /*  echo '<pre>';
            print_r($thumbnail_id);echo '</pre>';*/
           
         //   $attachment_id = get_field( 'workplace_thumb', 'workplaces_' . $category->term_id );
    
/*
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($attachment_id);
            echo '</pre>';*/
            if ( $thumbnail_id ) {

                $image        = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, 'woocommerce_single' );

                $image        = $image[0];

                $image_srcset = function_exists( 'wp_get_attachment_image_srcset' ) ? wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $thumbnail_id, 'shop_single_image_size' ) : false;

                $image_sizes  = function_exists( 'wp_get_attachment_image_sizes' ) ? wp_get_attachment_image_sizes( $thumbnail_id, 'shop_single_image_size' ) : false;

            }elseif ( ! $thumbnail_id ){
                $thumbnail_id_workplace             = get_term_meta( $category->term_id, 'workplace_thumb', true );
                $image        = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id_workplace, 'woocommerce_single' );

                $image        = $image[0];

                $image_srcset = function_exists( 'wp_get_attachment_image_srcset' ) ? wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $thumbnail_id_workplace, 'shop_single_image_size' ) : false;

                $image_sizes  = function_exists( 'wp_get_attachment_image_sizes' ) ? wp_get_attachment_image_sizes( $thumbnail_id_workplace, 'shop_single_image_size' ) : false;
            }
          
            
            else{

                $image        = wc_placeholder_img_src();

                $image_srcset = $image_sizes = false;

            }

    

            if ( $image ) {

                // Prevent esc_url from breaking spaces in urls for image embeds

                // Ref: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23605

                $image = str_replace( ' ', '%20', $image );

    

                echo '<div class="banner-box__image brand-grayscale">
                <a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $category, 'product_cat' ) ) . '" >
                <span class=" woocommerce-loop-category__thumbnail brand-grayscale" style="background-image :url(' . esc_url( $image ) . ');"></span></a>

            </div>';

            }

        }

        endif;
```